# Have to create a email reminder workflow ? check my workflow also

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email, reminder

I have a custom list on my site,which has a 'valid upto' field ,so it should send an email reminder a month before the 'valid upto' date,will this workflow work ? or should do some modifications ?
Kindly help !
TIA :)

[image: My Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

the above will work only one time. for your requirement you have to create a column isValid of type bool, set it to No default value.
Create 2 workflows on item created and item updated [image]

[image]

I have taken Created as Valid Upto, after 30 days check if valid up to is crossed if not update the isValid Column to yes which will trigger item update workflow, in which you have to check isValid, if true send email and then pause for 30 days and check the validup to date with current if its greater update the item with isValid as true which triggers the same workflow if not make it false which will end the workflow

In Item Update i Have just log my comments, please use actions

Comment: isValid column suggested by you is to serve the same purpose when an item is updated in the list ,am i right? for sending mail only for the one which is created,only the first workflow will be enough right? should i create 2 list workflows or two stages in single workflow?

Comment: can u please reply back @praveen ?

Comment: U have to create 2 work flow 1 for item update and another for item added , I have added attacuments as stages, is valid is to check the dates. As you mentioned . Sry for delay@Vish